# ...org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named '...' is defined - Как исправить?

Tags: java, spring

По наследству досталась многомодульная система с использованием Spring, Flyway, VAADIN и ещё чего-то. Возникла потребность добавить в БД новую таблицу и поля, а в интерфейс пользователя - связанные с ними возможности. С миграцией БД справился, а вот с пользовательским интерфейсом - затык. Неделю побороть не могу. При запуске получаю такой лог ошибки:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'providersRepository' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/pr.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'ntdEditionsDao' while setting bean property 'ntdEditions'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'ntdEditionsDao' is defined
com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.handleServiceException(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:1010)
com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.AbstractApplicationServlet.service(AbstractApplicationServlet.java:548)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:211)
io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:809)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Ошибка возникла после того,как в файл *pr.xml* была добавлена одна строка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="providersRepository" class="ru.leasoft.armspk.ProvidersRepository" factory-method="get"
      lazy-init="false" scope="singleton" init-method="initDatasourceMap">

    <property name="accidents" ref="accidentsDao"/>
    <property name="actions" ref="actionsDao"/>
    <property name="addressBook" ref="addressBook"/>
    <property name="attestationSpheres" ref="attestationSpheresDao"/>
    <property name="buildings" ref="buildingsDao"/>
    <property name="casualties" ref="casualtiesDao"/>
    <property name="commiteeTypes" ref="commiteeTypesDao"/>
    <property name="dangerSubstances" ref="dangerSubstancesDao"/>
    <property name="departments" ref="departmentsDao"/>
    <property name="devices" ref="devicesDao"/>
    <property name="educationService" ref="educationService"/>
    <property name="emergencies" ref="emergenciesDao"/>
    <property name="employees" ref="employeesDao"/>
    <property name="exams" ref="examsDao"/>
    <property name="expertCompanies" ref="expertCompaniesDao"/>
    <property name="externalInspections" ref="externalInspectionsDao"/>
    <property name="inspections" ref="inspectionsDao"/>
    <property name="inspectionPlans" ref="inspectionPlansDao"/>
    <property name="insuranceCompanies" ref="insuranceCompaniesDao"/>
    <property name="jobs" ref="jobsDao"/>
    <property name="licenses" ref="licensesDao"/>
    <property name="licensedActivities" ref="licensedActivitiesDao"/>
    <property name="noncompliances" ref="noncompliancesDao"/>
    <property name="normativeDocuments" ref="normativeDocumentsDao"/>
    <property name="organizations" ref="organizationsDao"/>
    <property name="ownershipCatalog" ref="ownershipDao"/>
    <property name="paragraphs" ref="paragraphsDao"/>
    <property name="pendingActivitiesService" ref="pendingActivities"/>
    <property name="plans" ref="plansDao"/>
    <property name="plants" ref="plantsDao"/>
    <property name="plas" ref="plasDao"/>
    <property name="practicePlans" ref="practicePlansDao"/>
    <property name="practices" ref="practicesDao"/>
    <property name="responsibilitySpheres" ref="responsibilitySpheresDao"/>
    <property name="supervisionDepartments" ref="supervisionDepartmentsDao"/>
    <property name="supervisionTypes" ref="supervisionTypesDao"/>
    //следующая строка была добавлена
    <property name="ntdEditions" ref="ntdEditionsDao"/>
    <property name="trainingPlans" ref="trainingPlansDao"/>
    <property name="trainings" ref="trainingsDao"/>

    <property name="reportPreparator" ref="reportPreparator"/>

    <property name="permissionChecker" ref="permissionChecker"/>
    <property name="permissionsService" ref="aclPermissionsService"/>
    <property name="usersService" ref="usersService"/>

    <property name="deviceExpertiseReporter" ref="deviceExpertiseReporter"/>
    <property name="buildingExpertiseReporter" ref="buildingExpertiseReporter"/>

    <property name="mediaService" ref="mediaService"/>
    <property name="logJournal" ref="logJournal"/>

</bean>
```

Добавил эту строку и все другие классы по аналогии с предыдущей строкой: supervisionTypes. Поиск в пути ссылки на supervisionTypesDao показал:

[image: Поиск в пути ссылки на supervisionTypesDao]

Для ntdEditionsDao сделано аналогично:

[image: Поиск в пути ссылки на ntdEditionsDao]

Не могу найти, где ещё нужно определить это ntdEditionsDao.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас опечатка в ресурсах.

Вы определили ntd**E**ditionsDao, но в NTDEditionsController обращаетесь к ntd**e**ditionsDao, а нужно к ntdEditionsDao.
Либо наоборот, исправьте DAO на ntdeditionsDao